# Why does my PC blue screen on first boot, then after restarting itself boot up normally?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd, bsod

I added an M.2 NVME drive to my computer yesterday, and cloned my original SSD with my Windows installation over to it.

The original SSD has since been formatted, and no other drives contain an operating system.

On initial boot from cold, Windows will bluescreen before it gets to the login screen with `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`, and then reboots itself. On subsequent "hot" reboots, there is no bluescreen.

I have tried running `sfc /scannow` with no faults found.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I unplugged my USB Bluetooth adapter and the computer now boots normally.</strike>

That was a red herring. I tried reseating all the components, even as far as buying a new CPU as I'd seen on other sites that my specific CPU and Motherboard combination could suffer bluescreens. It would even bluescreen when booting from a USB stick.

In the end, it turns out something must have gone wrong when cloning the old SSD to the new M.2 drive.

I reinstalled Windows to the SSD and removed the M.2 drive. It booted normally.
I reinstalled the M.2 drive and ran GParted to wipe it clean, then reinstalled Windows to it and booted from it.

Since then, there's been no issues. What went wrong? I don't know.